# Checking if a relationship exists

Tags: php, symfony2, propel

I'm using a many-to-many relationship between users and roles with propel:

```
<table name="user">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="username" required="true" type="varchar" primaryKey="true" size="50" />
</table>

<table name="role">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="role" required="true" type="varchar" size="20" primaryString="true" />
    <column name="name" required="true" type="varchar" size="50" />

    <unique>
        <unique-column name="role" />
        <unique-column name="name" />
    </unique>
</table>

<table name="user_role" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="user_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="role_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="user">
        <reference local="user_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="role">
        <reference local="role_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

This is how I check if a user has a role:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{       
    public function hasRole($checkRole)
    {
        foreach ($this->getRoles() as $role)
        {
            if ($role->getRole() == $checkRole)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This works, but I think it could be optimized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to loop throught the collection since you can directly query the database or your object if it is already loaded:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{       
    public function hasRole($checkRole)
    {
        $userWithRole = UserQuery::create()
            ->filterByRole($checkRole)
            ->findOne();

        return !is_null($userWithRole);
    }
}
```

You can either check that `$userWithRole` is not null like I did or if it is an instance of `User`.

If your objects are already hydrated you can avoid the query by querying the `Roles` collection:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{       
    public function hasRole($checkRole)
    {
        return $this->getRoles()->contains($checkRole);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the API of `Propel\Runtime\Collection\Collection` class and its derivatives. There are many more useful functions.